# adding firebase data in arraylist android is not working?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform

Hey I am working on an application. So I am getting the user ids from a collection called "Recent Chats" where I have added the users ids in keys. Now I am doing a query using that key (i got from Recent Chats) in the collection called "Users" to get that Particular Users data and then adding the data in the arraylist "usersarraylist". But  also want data inside the Recent Chats in that arraylist. How can i get that?

`

```
String recentUserId;

firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Recent_Chats").child(auth.getUid()).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        for (DataSnapshot snapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

             recentUserId = snapshot1.getKey();

//           want to add data from here to the same arralist "userArrayList"
             Recent_Chat_User recentChatUser = snapshot1.getValue(Recent_Chat_User.class);

//          Code to query on firestore 

            Query query = firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").whereEqualTo("uid", recentUserId);
            query.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {


                    List<DocumentSnapshot> list = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments();
                    for (DocumentSnapshot d : list)
                    {
                        Recent_Chat_User obj = d.toObject(Recent_Chat_User.class);
                        userArrayList.add(obj);

                    }

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                    if (userArrayList.isEmpty())
                    {
                        binding.imageView19.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        binding.noChat.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }else
                    {

                        binding.imageView19.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        binding.noChat.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                }
            });


        }

    }
```

`

So i want to get the collection "recent_chats" data in arraylist "userArrayList"

[Check the Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3YrW.png)

Comment: harsh brother i tried some methods but all turned irrevelants

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what the problem is.
What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: I am working on an chat app and this is the code to get the recent chats with whom i have interacted so while sending the messages i have saved the users ids in the recent chats in keys and now i m getting the keys and then i m querying the key to get the users details

Comment: Ok, then  what is wrong with shared code?

Comment: so as you can see that in the firestore query code i have added the data in the arraylist to show in the recyclerview and which is showing but i want to show some data from the collection "recent_chats" collection as well in the same arraylist how can i do that

Comment: It's hard for me to understand what you're looking for. Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot and indicate the exact data you want to get.

Comment: Sir please check i have added

Comment: Do you need to get everything under `Recent_Chats`? Or what exists under a specific UID?

Comment: by specific UID's Sir

Comment: Please edit your question and also add the content of your  `Recent_Chat_User` class.

Comment: sir as i have added the image of datase in databse there are three things and i need two out of them one is time to show the last message time of message and second is message

Comment: So are you willing to show us the `Recent_Chat_User` class?

Comment: yes sir i want to add this class data in the  arraylist called "userarraylist"

Comment: simaltaneously adding data from the firestore